# do we have or gate can take input 220v

Tags: voltage, digital-logic

I need to give power to a motor of garage door from two sources each one represent case 
so I need device like an or gate but take 220v as inputs & give 220v output to run the motor

Comment: Use a relay to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Any two switches or relays with their contacts connected in parallel function as an (inclusive) OR gate.

Note the distinction between "inclusive OR" and "exclusive OR". If you have two separate power sources that must never be connected to each other, you need the latter, and this will require the use of double-throw contacts.